# PySide delegate on QTableView with text and tick

Tags: python, qt, delegates, pyside, qtableview

I'm implementing a `QTableView` with a custom model and I need a cell that looks like this:
[image]

Currently I use the delegate below (adapted from other answers) to draw a flag (an html coloured text) on a single cell, clicking on the whole cell changes the flag.

```
class HTMLDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def Doc(self, options):
        if options.text == "0":
            return ""
        elif options.text == "1":
            return "<b><font align='right' color='green'>V</font></b>"
        elif options.text == "2":
            return "<font align='right' color='#FF8400'>!!</font>"
        elif options.text == "3":
            return "<b><font align='right' color='#CC0000'>F</font></b>"
        elif options.text == "4":
            return "<b><font align='right' color='#000000'>X</font></b>"

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options,index)

        style = QtGui.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None else options.widget.style()

        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()

        background = None
        doc.setHtml(self.Doc(options))

        options.text = ""
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter);

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        # Highlighting text if item is selected
        #if (optionV4.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        #    ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, optionV4.palette.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::HighlightedText));

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtGui.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options, None)
        painter.save()
        if background:
            painter.fillRect(options.rect, QtCore.Qt.yellow)
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))

        doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if not (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable) > 0:
            return False

        # Do not change the checkbox-state
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease or event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                return False
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() != QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and event.key() != QtCore.Qt.Key_Select:
                return False
        else:
            return False
                         
        # Change the flag-state
        self.setModelData(None, model, index)
        return False


    def setModelData (self, editor, model, index):
        '''
        The user wanted to change the old flag into the next
        '''
        #newValue = not bool(index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))
        #model.setData(index, newValue, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        oldFlagIndex = model.index(index.row(), COD_COL_FLAGS)
        oldFlag = model.data(oldFlagIndex)

        if type(oldFlag) == long:
            newFlag = oldFlag + 1
            if newFlag > 4:
                newFlag = 0
        else:
            newFlag = 0
        model.setData(index, newFlag, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
```

How can I accomplish this ?
The options that I have in mind are:

- A delegate that draws text (rich or simple) along with a pixmap to the right
- A delegate that draws two strings of text (one normal and one rich, or both rich text) aligned one to the left and one to the right

As an exercise, but not required for the app, it would be nice to trigger the flag change only when clicking on it instead of the whole cell.

Thanks

Comment: What other answers? That would be really helpful to provide links to so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

The paint event has an argument called option that should contain a rect object. That rect object is the bounds for what is painted. You should be able to change the width of that rect and create a new rect for where you want the second part painted.

```
rect = options.rect
options.rect = QtCore.QRect(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width()/2, rect.height())
style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter);
options.rect = QtCore.QRect(rect.x()+rect.width()/2, rect.y(), rect.width()/2, rect.height())
options.text = "right side"
style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter);
```